# Let $a\in \mathbb R$. Resolve $\sqrt{2x -1} -x + a = 0 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solutions: $x = a + 1 + \sqrt{2a}$ and $x = a + 1 -\sqrt{2a}$

My attempt:
$\sqrt{2x - 1} = x - a$, we have $x \geq a$. So

$$2x - 1 = x^2 - 2xa + a^2 \iff x^2 - 2(2a + 2) + a^2 +1 = 0$$

We have, $\Delta = 8a$. The solutions is $x = a + 1 \pm \sqrt{2a}$.

Since $x \geq a$, is easy to see that $x = a + 1 +\sqrt{2a}$, but how can I see the other solution?

Like $a + 1 -\sqrt{2a} = x \geq a \iff 1 - \sqrt{2a} \geq 0$.

What I do now?

I didn't see a lower bond for $a$?

Comment: You have correctly concluded that if  $\sqrt{2x-1} - x + a=0$ is true for some real numbers $x$ and $a$, then $x\geq a$ and there are *at most two solutions* (and you have found both potential solutions). You can further conclude that if $a< 0$ then there are no solutions (since $\sqrt{2a}$ would be imaginary), and if $a+1-\sqrt{2a}<a$ then there is at most one solution. For example if $a=1$ then there is only one solution $x=2+\sqrt{2}$ (you can verify the other option $x=2-\sqrt{2}$ does not work). Furthermore, if $a=0$ then there is only one solution.

Comment: the 2 solutions are correct. And you wrote wrongly: $a + 1 - \sqrt{2a} \geq a$

Comment: What do you mean?  I often have typos and mistakes, but I do not see anything I wrote wrongly here. If $a+1-\sqrt{2a}<a$ then we cannot have a solution $x=a+1-\sqrt{2a}$ and so there is only one solution (namely, $x=a+1+\sqrt{2a}$). You can indeed verify that the case $a=1$ has only one solution $x=2+\sqrt{2}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As noticed, your work is fine and you are almost done, one solution is $x_1 = a + 1 + \sqrt{2a}$ which is always fine for any $a\ge 0$ while for the other solution $x_2 = a + 1 - \sqrt{2a}$ we need to check the condition

$$x_2=a + 1 - \sqrt{2a}\ge a \iff 1 - \sqrt{2a}\ge 0 \iff a\le \frac12$$

therefore for $0\le a \le \frac12$ we have two real solutions, which are two equal roots for $a=0$, while for $a>\frac12$ we have only one real solution.

Comment: +1 but minor edit is needed for the case $a=0$ (see my very first comment regarding that case, it has 1 solution not 2).

Comment: @Michael Thanks! We can also consider them two equal roots for $a=0$. I fix that point!